# Making a GET request that uses POST method - Javascript to C# API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have a situation where I'm required to encrypt data in flight from a JavaScript based application (Chrome Extension popup.html) to an API hosted in a .NET MVC website(C#).

I can run the request as a GET but project requirements make it necessary to encrypt the parameters I'm sending. For example if I was searching for all people named 'John' I need to encrypt 'John' in flight.

My JavaScript application is using jsencrypt and a RSA (public) key provided by the website in other APIs that work quite well to return counts.

If my GET version of the link looks like this:

`<span class="person" id="personList">Person: <a href="' + url + 'Persons/Search?find=' + search + '" target="_blank">'+ query +'</a></span>`

On the .NET website end, this request is processed into a view that generates a table using a database call. As you can see in my link the results are populated onto a new tab in the browser.

How would you recommend changing it to calling a POST method and getting the same result as a GET?

**EDIT**
I tried to employ an AJAX function to make the POST but it doesn't like the data element:

````
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                url: repurl + 'Persons/Search',
                timeout:30000,
                type: "POST",
                data: {body: encryptedmsg},
                success : function(msg) {
     
                     if (msg.ws_resultat.result_ok == true)
                     {
                        alert('ok');    
                     }
                     else 
                     {
                       alert('some thing went wrong, plz try again');
                     }
                 }
     
                });
});```
````

Comment: Look into AJAX calls.  You can send your parameters via POST method using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, I see a couple examples. My a tags are created using a listener that calls a function, so I'd need the function I'm creating for the AJAX to wait until the a tags are created or else I'm going to get an error, correct?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to use a Promise so that you can wait for the function to return before firing the AJAX call.